# Example of collectionFS' transformWrite in meteor

Tags: meteor

Can any one please show me a concrete working example of transformWrite. At the moment I've got this example which I am not sure how to plug into my code: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#transformwrite--transformread

My attempt code is as below. Please show me how to make it work.

> ```
>   FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
>       file = transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
>           readStream.pipe(writeStream);
>         }
>       Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
>         // Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
>       });
>     });
> ```

Comment: Oh and how do I change the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the transform on the store, not during insert. Here is how I do it on [step3d.com](http://step3d.com) (a simple 3D CAD-file viewer):

```
transformServer = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    if (fileObj.extension() == "stl") {
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);   // can handle as is
    } else if (fileObj.extension() == "step"
               || fileObj.extension() == "stp") {
        step2stl(fileObj, readStream, writeStream);  // convert from step to stl format
    } else {
        console.log("no idea how to handle", fileObj.extension());
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    }
};

var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("files", {
    transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        transformServer(fileObj, readStream, writeStream);
    }
});

Files = new FS.Collection("files", {
    stores: [store]
});
```

Afterwards, any insertion into the `Files` collection will be transformed before storing the file in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As per the comment above how do I change the file name? I see you are changing the extension/format in step2stl which you don't show above. I want to rename the files as I am storing them so that all files are stored with a user id corresponding to the current user. I am doing this so that later I use wild card search to search for a specific user's files.

Comment: you can attach whatever properties you want to fileObj. If you are storing in mongodb then the filename hardly matters.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I read through the documentation. I see fileObj is changed in beforeWrite. Is beforeWrite defined on the store as well? If so what if the file name I want to change to is decided on the fly and my store is defined globally, what then?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to change the name property by using fileObj.name() method during insert. Thanks a stack dude. You shed some light. Being the tech head that I am it would be interesting still to know how/where beforeWrite is defined.

Comment: according to the link, `beforeWrite` seems to be defined on the store, just like the transforms. So yeah, I think that would be a good place for you to modify the fileObj.